# How to import the data from .MYD into MATLAB?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I just obtained a bunch of MySQL data stored in raw MySQL ( MyISAM table) format in a `.MYD` file.

I now wish to start data analysis over those data. All I need to do is just reading the numbers into my MATLAB and process them.

What is the easiest way of doing so? I am using Mac OS, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a mysql database and dropping the file into a (non running at the time) mysql server is certainly one way to get to the stage where you have the data  in a form you can re-export it.

I am not familiar with MACos locations but in linux the data structure is :

```
/var/lib/mysql/databasename/*.MYI and MYD
```

I would be leery of trying to extract an ISAM file using anything other than mysql frankly.

Maybe someone else knows better, but I don't :-)